# How to completely remove my Emacs?

Tags: apt, uninstall, make, emacs

I downloaded Emacs source files, and installed it using `make`. After installing Emacs successfully, I manually removed the downloaded source files to save disk space. Now I want to remove Emacs and I tried to use `sudo apt-get purge emacs`. But it says Emacs has not been installed and will not be removed. But I can run Emacs by typing `emacs` in the terminal. Also the command `which emacs` shows the result `/usr/local/bin/emacs`.

Why can't `apt-get` detect it? How can I remove Emacs completely in this situation? My OS is Ubuntu 12.04, and my Emacs version is 24.3.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apt-get can not detect the applications which you have installed from source.Actually every source file will have uninstall script also but unfortunately you have removed the source file.

You may still do this. In the terminal type as

```
locate emacs
```

it will list all it footprints in the system , then remove those emacs footprints by using rm command carefully.

Comment: So I should keep the source file in order to remove the application in the future. When I decide to remove it, I run `make uninstall`, and then delete the downloaded source file. Is that right? Should I run `make clean` after `make uninstall`?

Comment: @YangWenhao It may be `make remove` or some other command, but yes, when you install software from source, you need to keep the source code around so you can do `make uninstall` or similar to remove the software.  Source-built software isn't managed by the packaging system because it's not existing as a Debian package.

Comment: @ThomasW. Thank you for your help. I know the right way.

Comment: `locate emacs` will not "list all it footprints in the system", it will simply show you files which have 'emacs' in the name. With a program as large as emacs, many of the added files likely don't have 'emacs' in the name or path.

Answer (score 12):

You haven't installed Emacs with the package manager. As you have installed it from source tarball, try this way.

1. Check emacs version.

   ```
   $ emacs --version
   ```
2. Download the same emacs version you have installed in the past.

   ```
   $ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-$VERSION.tar.xz
   ```
3. Extract tarball.

   ```
   $ tar xJvf emacs-$VERSION.tar.xz
   ```
4. Run ./configure to generate the make file. If you remember the option you have given when you install it, add those command line flags, too. (e.g. --with-x=no)

   ```
   $ cd emacs-$VERSION
   $ ./configure
   ```
5. Do make uninstall to uninstall.

   ```
   $ sudo make uninstall
   ```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 11):

It is *not* enough to

```
sudo apt-get remove emacs
```

You have to do

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove emacs emacs23 emacs24 emacs25 emacs26 \
                    emacs-bin-common emacs-common emacs-el
```

Then

```
locate emacs
```

Comment: + `emacs24` too

Comment: I am not sure this would help or apply to the OP. It looks like he compiled and installed from source.

Answer (score 5):

For me removing emacs-gtk worked

```
sudo apt-get remove emacs-gtk
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt remove --purge emacs-bin-common emacs-el emacs-gtk
```

This command worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Using `checkinstall`

1. Close all package managers
2. Download the archive again
3. Compile emacs again
4. Install the package checkinstall

   ```
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
5. Install emacs with

   ```
   sudo checkinstall
   ```

   to overwrite you previous installation and to have a deb package. That's the trick.
6. Remove the emacs package, the command is shown after the installation via checkinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and worked for me :

1. Go the emacs installed Icon in the apps:
2. Click the right button > Show Details
3. Click on the uninstalled button.
4. Go to terminal > emacs--version.
5. Nothing is there.
6. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

**Using apt**

```
sudo apt remove emacs
```

followed by

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

this will remove both emacs-terminal and emacs-GUI

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to uninstall emacs which was installed through `ppa:kelleyk/emacs`.

I initially tried

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove emacs$VERSION
```

it removed some emacs files but the emacs itself does not removed. when I went to my terminal and do `emacs --version`, I can still open emacs.

I then reinstalled `emacs$VERSION` once more

```
sudo apt install emacs$VERSION
```

then again purged the emacs

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove emacs$VERSION
```

Now its completely removed.