# Remove Emacs 26 from Ubuntu Software

Tags: 20.04

I try to remove Emacs 26 in order to install 27, but in Ubuntu Software Updater i cant remove the software. There are no errors shown, when i remove it.

When i check on the command line it is showing:
emacs version 26

I just want to update to emacs 27, but of course it is not possible with 26.

Comment: Try removing with the command line: `sudo apt autoremove emacs`. Then install the snap version to get [emacs 27](https://snapcraft.io/emacs).

Answer (score 2):

To remove `emacs`, please see [How to completely remove my Emacs](https://askubuntu.com/a/377248/660555):

I did following:

```
sudo apt autoremove emacs
sudo apt autoremove emacs26
sudo apt-get remove emacs-bin-common emacs-common emacs-el emacs-gtk
```

---

To install emacs version 27 do following:

```
sudo snap install emacs --classic
```